# how i can Scrolling table for some validating

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I have a table that generate with a class(ef CodeFirst) now I want some validating for new added values for 2 fields...
i have list that have all of my table but i don't know how to do for Comparison in new values and saved values.

```
public static bool Validating(TimeSpan start,TimeSpan end)
    {
        ContexManager contex = new ContexManager();
        List<Shift> sList = Shift.GetAllShift();
        Shift sels = new Shift();
        foreach (Shift item in sList)
        {
         //it have this two fields
            //item.MyStartTime;
            //item.MyEndTime
        }


        return false;
    }
```

it's time validation i want new start and new end not between start an end before i saved.
almost i want how to scrolling the table for create `if()` Conditions